# Android - Check if there are validation errors in the current view

Tags: android, validation

Let's say I got a fragment (of a `ViewPager`) with an `EditText` and I got somewhere this line of code: `myEditText.setError("there is an error");`

Now I want to know if I should allow the user to move forward to the next page. How can I check if there are any validation errors in the ENTIRE fragment (not just the single edit text from my example) in order to determine if the user can move to the next page? something like `if(!this.containsErrors()) return true;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check the return value of `TextView`'s `getError()`:

> Returns the error message that was set to be displayed with
>   setError(CharSequence), or null if no error was set or if it the error
>   was cleared by the widget after user input.

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(myEditText.getError()) {
     // go ahead, no error set!
     return true; 
}
```

a simple routine to make the check could be:

```
   boolean isErrorFree() {
      ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) getView();
      if (viewGroup == null) {
            return true;
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
           View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
           if (view instanceof TextView) {
               if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(((TextView)view).getError()) {
                       return false;
               }
           }
      }
      return true;
   }
```

check for typo

Comment: this is an answer only for the one edit text. I want to check if the entire fragment doesn't contain any widget with an error and not by checking all of them one by one

Comment: there is no other way *imo*. Btw, in order to call setError, you have to check if the widget's content satisfies your constraints. All in all you could write a routine that loops on all the children of the fragment's view and check if the current child is a TextView and do the same check

Comment: Yeah I do that but I thought there might be a method like Fragment.checkIfContainsErrors(this) or something like that

Comment: no, there is no such a thing. Fragment is a portion UI, that works independently from its content.

Comment: Just to be sure, I'm waiting a day and if no one else give an answer, I'll accept yours